# asp.net c# - Generic handler (ashx) and BasePage

Tags: c#, handler, ashx, ihttphandler, app-code

In my C# asp.net project I have a BasePage (in \App_Code), and ordinary aspx pages inherit the BasePage. The challenge is to access the BasePage when there is no direct inheritance.

To get access to the BasePage from my MasterPage I do the following:

```
private BasePage MyBasePage
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return (BasePage)Page;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new BasePage();
        }
    }
}
```

Thus I can access the BasePage by MyBasePage.myVoid()

From a UserControl it's as simple as (this.Page as BasePage).myVoid().

But in a generic handler (ashx), that inherits the IHttpHandler, how can I get access to the BasePage?

Comment: If it doesn't inherit from BasePage you can't pretend it does. Sounds like an XY problem so please explain what you're trying to achieve

Comment: The BasePage has for instance some code to check if the user has access to a particular file, and I'd like the handler to reuse the same code.
The handler return files that are in a folder that is set as a hiddenSegment, so I guess need the handler to actually do the access test – if not, everybody could access the files just by going directly to the handler.